# Delete item from database and update listview?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I have a database with the method:

```
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

I have a general idea about how to utilize it, but its just not deleting items. I have no idea how to find out what row the item is in. Here's the listview with the database in it, with the on select event:

```
private void Items() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ItemsList.this);
    dlgAlert.setTitle("Something Here");
    dlgAlert.setMessage("What would you like to do?");
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Delete",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//This is where it should be finding what row the item is in and deleting it...

                }
            });
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

Comment: It's not possible for anyone to answer this question. You need to do is do more research on how to develop android based database applications.

Comment: do you have a custom adapter to show your listview? Usually you set the item of the listview to onItemClickListener. There you can be mor flexible to get what you want

Comment: Well I'm assuming i need to call something like: `db.deleteContact(//then somehow find the id of the row);` I just don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have used an adapter to fill the list view. And generally when dealing with android database there is an autoincrement column  _id that we have to give in. You can use argument "int which" to get the entry that was clicked. The int argument will be equal to the _id(your database's auto increment column) get your database to a cursor, move your cursor to "which" and delete the item accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In you Database when you are saving any item you may have assigned some unique identifier like _id or Item_no or something like that.

So when you get data in cursor and assign Custom adapter to List at that time in your GetView method in Custom adapter you can get value of that Unique identifier. after getting it set tag to view with your identification no. so that when you click on any view in list you will get its tag value. and pass it to your method item(string tag) like this. and when alert button clicked you can call database delete method which matches the given identifier in method. so that it can delete exactly that record.

Hope it Helps!!